# EditTextPreference crashes

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I have created a `PreferenceScreen`, which worked really nice, but I recently added two `EditTextPreferences`, and there seems to be something wrong. As soon as one clicks an `EditTextPreference`, the application crashes.

This is my **preferences.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/title_telephone">

        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_checkbox_telephone_recording"
            android:key="checkbox_preference_telephone_recording"
            android:summary="@string/preference_recording_summary"
            android:title="@string/checkbox_telephone_recording" />

        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_checkbox_telephone_accel"
            android:key="checkbox_preference_telephone_accel"
            android:summary="@string/preference_accel_summary"
            android:title="@string/checkbox_telephone_accel" />

    </PreferenceCategory>
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Allgemeine Informationen">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="none"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:key="textfield_preference_client_ID"
            android:title="@string/textbox_client_ID_title"
            android:summary="0" />
        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="none"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:key="textfield_preference_version_ID"
            android:title="@string/textbox_version_ID_title"
            android:summary="@string/version_ID" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is the **stacktrace**:

```
Process: com.applications.philipp.apkinson, PID: 13798
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1307)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2871)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:412)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:381)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:282)
at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.onStart(DialogFragment.java:406)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2000)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1102)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5373)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Can anybody help me with this? I didn't manage to solve this. I want the `EditTextPreferences` not to be clickable, but I tried it without this xml argument as well and it would crash.

**UPDATE**

When I replace the `EditTextPreference` with `Preference`, everything works great. But still, this does not really explain why I run into trouble with my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there because you try put link on resource that does not exist. May be problem here: android:summary="0". Try to change it on @string resource with value "0"